# How to save a file with different extension according to Boolean value

Tags: c++, qt

I want to save files according to the value of a Boolean I have in my program. if Boolean true extension must be (".me") and if false extension will be (".you").
I am using this line of code to filter my extensions:

```
QString Save = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save File to:", QDir::currentPath(), tr("DIAG (*.me *.you)" ));
```

Comment: `if (flag) extension = ".me"; else extenstion = ".you";` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
QString save = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save File to:", QDir::currentPath(), bool_value ? tr("DIAG (*.me)" : tr("DIAG (*.you)"));
```